# Matte Film On LCD Displays

Tags: lcd, display, materials

What is the technical name of the matte material/film that is put on LCD Displays?

Also what would be the method of applying such film on a blank lcd screen (if possible)?

EDIT: (Not my picture, but it illustrates what I'm talking about, left is film and right is no film)

[image]

EDIT 2:

Just in case you were wondering, I'm planning on using this for a few portable tablet-like monitors that i want to also use outside and this seems good for reducing glare and improving overall look of the monitor. The screens i current want to use this on are 16.5 inch and 5.5 1080p lcd displays

Would i be able to achieve that? What are The Downsides?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: @Wossname, On it now. :) EDIT: Done

Comment: Ok, so this is the outermost layer on the finished product. Depending on the application (domestic / industrial) it could be a layer intended to be a diffuser for increasing the viewing angle, or as an anti-glare measure.  Are you referring to PC monitors or something more specialised?  Do you want to apply this to your own product?

Comment: @Wossname, Well yeah it is for a product that im making (non touchscreen)

Comment: You seem determined not to give us much of an insight into the nature of your application.  There are dozens of factors that would affect the implementation of such a feature.  Not least of which is the environment into which the product is designed to be deployed.

Comment: @Wossname sorry for not clarifying that, i tried to clear it up in the post, should give you some more insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called *diffuser*. It homogenizes the light from the back or the edges of the display to create a homogenous apparel of the background illumination.

Alternatively it is possible, that you mean the *anti glare* or *matte* foil, which reduces specular reflection on displays.

---

According to your edit2, I'm quite sure, that you mean *anti glare* foil, which is a good choice for outdoor applications. You should also consider a rather bright background illumination, as it needs to concur with the huge amount of daylight which is reaching the eye of the  user.

Comment: Great, can you provide any references or product sources?

Comment: @Deimantux You'll find various further information with the provided keywords.

Comment: do you reckon you could update according to my edit on the post?

Comment: Awesome, would upvote if i could :)

Answer (score 0):

The protective film may be added for a great variety of reasons:

It may be harder scratch resistant film if the screen uses a pen.

It may be for diffusion (both glare and screen).

It may be for polarization.

It may be for security (lowers visible angle).

It may be to reduce smudge marks due to a touch interface.

All of these applications may change the formulation of the film material and its exposed surface. Usually for any given product in the market they are called screen protectors of course.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for the function but for the name.

Comment: The name varies depending on function.